# Angular 4 + Universal Redirect to 404 page if found any invalid Url

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal, angular4-forms

I am using Angular 4 + universal for my application and using below code to redirect to 404 page if some unknown URL is found.

```
  {
path: '',
component: FullLayoutComponent,
data: {
  title: 'Home'
},
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/core/components/static/static.module#StaticModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'move',
    loadChildren: 'app/core/components/move/move.module#MoveModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: 'app/core/components/account/account.module#AccountModule'
  },
  { path: "**",redirectTo:"404"}
]
```

}

it redirects to localhost:4200/404 for any unknown URL but if I go to URL localhost:4200 then also it redirects me to 404 .

any leads will surely help a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to as follows -:

```
  {
path: '',
component: FullLayoutComponent,
data: {
 title: 'Home'
},
children: [
  {
   path: '',
   loadChildren:'app/core/components/static/static.module#StaticModule'
},
{
 path: 'move',
 loadChildren: 'app/core/components/move/move.module#MoveModule'
},
{
 path: 'account',
 loadChildren: 'app/core/components/account/account.module#AccountModule'
}

 ]
},

{ path: "**",redirectTo:"404"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the most important part is missing in the answers so far: You should not only do a redirect but set the correct status code. In order to do so you need the request object in your Angular code. Then you can access the response object that is usually attached to the request - at least in express.

```
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
              @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.response.status(404);
    }
  }

}
```

If you are using express and ng universal express engine you can pass request and response into dependency injection like this:

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    extraProviders: [
      // make req and response accessible when angular app runs on server
      <ValueProvider>{
        provide: REQUEST,
        useValue: options.req
      },
      <ValueProvider>{
        provide: RESPONSE,
        useValue: options.req.res,
      },
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
})
```

Since I just stumbled upon this problem myself, I recorded my procedure in a blog post. If you need more guidance, take a look:

https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-universal-handle-404-set-status-codes/

Comment: Hi Can K, I added the specified code, but I still keep getting a status 200 or status 304. I realised inject.preload.js has a GET error but i'm not sure how to resolve this

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I'm a bit confused as to why this is only applicable to server side and not client side. Why are you checking if its not a browser before sending the 404?  Should we not also send a 404 from the client?

Comment: You cant send 404 in client and the response is injected with optional, the if check could also be on response. If I remember correctly, response will be undefined if the code runs on the client.